# I can't pass these domain challenges with letsencrypt

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a website running on an ec2 instance. It's running with pm2, and I'm able to connect to it and load it in my browser directly with it's elastic ip address.

My domain is routing traffic to it correctly, according to curl. However, the site gives Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG when trying to connect in browser.

I'm trying to enable ssl certs on the website using letsencrypt.

I have nginx running and active. I'm using iptables to redirect traffic from ports 80 and ports 443 to port 3000 (where my site is).

but everytime I use this command:

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d xxx.app -d www.xxx.app
```

The domain challenges fail:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for xxx.app
http-01 challenge for www.xxx.app
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain xxx.app
Challenge failed for domain www.xxx.app
http-01 challenge for xxx.app
http-01 challenge for www.xxx.app
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: xxx.app
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://xxx.app/.well-known/acme-challenge/uYinEDb9EVI4Ki0fti-IX3T84qenxfkq2x8fAJ50XzU
   [xx.xx.xx.xx]"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style
   data-next-hide-fouc=\"true\">body{display:none}</style><noscript
   data-next-hide-fouc=\"true\"><sty"

   Domain: www.xxx.app
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.xxx.app/.well-known/acme-challenge/y6tpQJ6u7hXSgLGabwTNRY4LtStTsW8h8y0r20Dp1GQ
   [xx.xx.xx.xx]: "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style
   data-next-hide-fouc=\"true\">body{display:none}</style><noscript
   data-next-hide-fouc=\"true\"><sty"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Not easy to answer to you question.

Did you checked your DNS ? Did you tried to access to http://www.xxx.app/.well-known/acme-challenge/y6tpQJ6u7hXSgLGabwTNRY4LtStTsW8h8y0r20Dp1GQ from a browser ?

Are you using some IP/authent restrictions ? Are you using a "proxy" service like Cloudflare ?

Comment: You have to be able to connect to the HTTP version of the site.  Are you able to do so?

Comment: i believe the problem is with the iptables port fowarding that you have done. Try removing the iptable rule and generate the ssl certs in standalone mode (`--certonly`) and then pass that cert files to your express or nodejs web app and then using iptable just redirect the 443/https traffic to port 3000

Comment: To NRE: when I go to the /acme page i get the same SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG I get when just going to my page.

Comment: To stdunbar: It works with curl.  curl -v http://xxx.app works fine. But going through a browser yields same error as above.

Comment: To Akash: This actually helped me passed the challenge, but now my page goes to nginx. Thanks, I at least am heading in the right direction now.